# execute laravel tests in docker fails

Tags: laravel, docker, phpunit

I have the following bash script for Laravel gitlab CI deployment

```
docker-compose -p project exec php8 bash -c '
  composer install --working-dir="dashboard"  &&
  wp acorn config:clear --allow-root &&
  wp acorn view:clear --allow-root &&
  wp acorn optimize:clear --allow-root &&
  wp rewrite flush --allow-root &&
  php dashboard/artisan migrate &&
  php dashboard/artisan optimize:clear &&
  php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testsuite=Feature'
```

but the test are not executed because of the following error `Could not open input file: vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` if I `ls` the directory everything seems to be on the right place. How to debug this issue

Comment: seems weird your phpunit is located there, it should be in vendor/bin/phpunit. But instead what about running php artisan test which is a wrapper for phpunit but in artisan?

Comment: @mrhn with php artisan I get the same error message

Comment: seems like all your other commands you run in dashboard/ what happens if you do php dashboard/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testsuite=Feature'

Comment: like that the Argument is not getting passed I have as output just the available commands

Comment: I got it working `docker-compose -p project exec php8 bash -c 'cd dashboard && ls && php artisan test --testsuite=Feature'`